# KMS Activation issue - PROVIDER NOT FOUND

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, kms

I have an error when trying to add keys for win 2016, office 2016 or windows 10 on Windows Server 2012 R2 KMS Server.

I have update everything and [did this also.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3086418)

And I get this error

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxtGs.png)

in cmd I see it is added:

```
> Name: Windows(R), ServerStandard edition Description: Windows(R)
> Operating System, VOLUME_KMS_WS16 channel Activation ID:  Application
> ID: 5 Extended PID:  Product Key Channel: Volume:CSVLK Installation
> ID:  Use License URL:
> https://activation-v2.sls.microsoft.com/SLActivateProduct/SLActivateProduct.asmx?configextension=Retail
> Validation URL:
> https://validation-v2.sls.microsoft.com/SLWGA/slwga.asmx Partial
> Product Key:  License Status: Licensed Remaining Windows rearm count:
> 999 Remaining SKU rearm count: 1001 Trusted time: 28-11-16 12:45:06
```

But what is this PROVIDER NOT FOUND error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had this issue when we add Office 2016 and Windows 10 Licenses to our KMS server (Windows 2012 R2 server). You will need to uninstall the current license file and install the new one. 
Here a Step by Step guide about how to do it. https://blog.workinghardinit.work/2015/08/12/find-and-update-your-kms-service-host-key-to-activate-windows-10/

Comment: Hello, I have not tried your solution because I am waiting from answer from Microsoft. They say this is a bug. So i will reply when i get the answer from them. Thanks

Comment: Yes, Is a bug, This is why you need to uninstall the current license file and install the new one.